# Send pdf to email laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am begineer developer. I want to attach pdf file and send to email with LARAVEL. please help me. I'm beginner, i tried some methods and googled it but not worked.

Comment: Your problem is creating the PDF or sending an email with an attachment?

Comment: not, i have pdf and i want to attach and send it to email with LARAVEL

Comment: recommended: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsZuz1q87xs

Comment: and how send pdf type?

Comment: what would i write in ->attach() which is in this tutorial

Comment: The path to your pdf file of course

Answer (score 0):

You can attach any file to the email using `attach` method. Check example in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#attachments)